# I'm trying to add an int to itself in a second thread and nothing is changing in my main thread

Tags: android, multithreading

I'm make a live wallpaper. And I'm having issues with trying to multithread my sprites frame changes. I have an update method and a draw method

```
public void update() {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        currentFrame = ++currentFrame % 2;

    }

    public void Draw(Canvas c, int sx, int sy){
        update();
        x = sx;
        y = sy;
        int srcX =  currentFrame * width;
        int srcY = 0;
        Rect src = new Rect(srcX,srcY,srcX+width,srcY+height);
        Rect dst = new Rect(x,y,x+width,y+height);
        c.drawBitmap(b, src, dst, null);
```

I tried to make a class

```
public class SecondThread extends Thread{
            public void run(){
                seaweed.update();

            }
            }
```

That runs the update in its own thread so they can sleep at different time lengths. One sleeps 50 the other sleeps 500. If put the SecondThread class inside the spirte class it just sets on the first frame and if I put in my wallpaper engine class and try and start it it does like one step and then crashes. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling [postInvalidate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postInvalidate%28%29) on your View after updating the int. Something like:

```
public void update() {

    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    currentFrame = ++currentFrame % 2;
    YourViewClass.this.postInvalidate();
}

public void Draw(Canvas c, int sx, int sy){
    update();
    x = sx;
    y = sy;
    int srcX =  currentFrame * width;
    int srcY = 0;
    Rect src = new Rect(srcX,srcY,srcX+width,srcY+height);
    Rect dst = new Rect(x,y,x+width,y+height);
    c.drawBitmap(b, src, dst, null);
```

Comment: It's saying my wallpaper engine cannot be resolved to this type.